# Looping knitr options

Tags: r, knitr

I'm curious, is there a way to incorporate changes in knitr options in a loop?  For example, if I wanted to loop through and see how the same block of code looked in all different knitr themes, my first guess would be:

\documentclass{article}

```
\begin{document}

<<test>>=
themes<-knit_theme$get()


for (a.theme in themes){

  knit_theme$set(a.theme)

  a <- 3+5
   b<- sum(1:10, na.rm=T)
  for(g in 1:10) z<-0
}
@

\end{document}
```

And yet, this produces some pretty odd output.  Is there a way to use loops like this, to dynamically change output, or perhaps dynamically include or not include certain chunks?

Comment: If you're simply trying to see the look/feel of all the themes to decide which one to use, [this gallery](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks - that's how this started, but, it actually goes to a larger question I have about mixing R and LaTeX code that this might answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not possible. One document only supports one theme, since all the colors are defined in the preamble, and there can only be one set of definitions. If you want different themes, they must live in different documents. See this gist for how to do it in HTML as well as a gallery of built-in themes in `knitr`: https://gist.github.com/3422133

With LaTeX/PDF, you can also do a loop on an Rnw document to generate PDF's for different themes and use `\includegraphics{}` to include them in the main TeX document. You can probably figure it out since it is not very different with the HTML example above.